# C++: Making a dynamically initialized variable available to other .cpp files

Tags: c++

I have a `int vertexCount` variable that's initialized by reading a text file on a `loader.cpp` and I want to make it available to a separate `model.cpp` file.

Should I declare it as

> extern vertexCount

on `model.cpp`? Or on a `.h`?

Comment: How is it "dynamically initialized"?

Comment: I'd say none of the above. Make a class that supports the operations you can perform on the data, and keep the data storage internal (as a `std::vector` or so). Then pass an instance of that class around to operate on.

Comment: Either way, it makes no difference. In model.cpp you can declare extern int vertexCount and everybody will be happy.

Comment: Here be dragons: however you do it, how can you be certain that `model.cpp` will only access the value after then initialisation has happened? In C++ there are few guarantees about order of initialisation between different translation units.

Comment: @Alan: well, for such a guarantee one needs to move the free-standing variable inside a _class_, which will take care of the initialization. But for small and simple projects approach like "okay, I should not touch this variable until that code finishes" is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forward-declare `extern int vertexCount;` in the header where it is appropriate for this variable to be, and declare (i.e., allocate memory) in the .cpp: `int vertexCount;`. You can either initialize it immediately (`int vertexCount = 1;`) or later in the code in any of the files containing code (you'll need to include the header, of course).

It's however your responsibility not to access the variable until it's really initialized.

You can consider as well putting the variable into a class, which will ensure proper initialization in either constructor or on first access (you'll need a kind of getter), or in the background, etc. This way is perhaps the cleanest.

Comment: The .cpp that initializes it should implement the header where it was declared as extern, right?

Comment: @omgzor: Well, it's not actually necessary, but it's the usual way. Of course, the .cpp file should `#include` the header (but I'm not sure if it's strictly necessary).

Answer (score 1):

I'd declare something like this in your .h:

```
extern VertexCount *vertexCount;
```

Then *define* (allocate space for) it in one and only one .cpp file (for example, "main.cpp"):

```
#include "myheader.h"  // contains the "extern"
...
VertexCount *vertexCount = NULL;
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want vertexCount to be an int (I realized I didn't write it, hehe, I'm getting too used to Python) , please explain why are you declaring it as a pointer? Was it simply because of my omission?

Comment: Yes, it was simply because of the omission.  It sounds like you want "extern int vertexCount" in the .h header, and "int vertexCount = 0" in the .cpp.